# How to insert data using AJAX to phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#register-submit-btn").click(function(){
            var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
            var fname = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
            var lname = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
            var phn = document.getElementById("phone").value;
            var emailid  = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var pass  = document.getElementById("password").value;
            var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;
            if(fname == ""){
                document.getElementById("first_name_err").innerHTML= "First name not be enmpty";
                document.getElementById("first_name_err").style.display = "block";
                $('#first_name').focus();
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("first_name_err").innerHTML= "";
                document.getElementById("first_name_err").style.display = "none";
            }
            if (lname==""){
                document.getElementById("last_name_err").innerHTML= "Last name not be enmpty";
                document.getElementById("last_name_err").style.display = "block";
                $('#last_name').focus();
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("last_name_err").innerHTML= "";
                document.getElementById("last_name_err").style.display = "none";
            }
            if (phn=="") {
                document.getElementById("phone_err").innerHTML= "Phone Number not be enmpty";
                document.getElementById("phone_err").style.display = "block";
                $('#phone').focus();
            }
            else if(phn.length != 10){
                document.getElementById("phone_err").innerHTML= "Phone Number should be  10-digits";
                document.getElementById("phone_err").style.display = "block";
                $('#phone').focus();
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("phone_err").innerHTML= "";
                document.getElementById("phone_err").style.display = "none";
            }
            if(emailid == ""){
                document.getElementById("email_err").innerHTML= "Email not be enmpty";
                document.getElementById("email_err").style.display = "block";
                $('#email').focus();
            }
            else if (!mailformat.test(emailid)){
                document.getElementById("email_err").innerHTML= "Invalid Email";
                document.getElementById("email_err").style.display = "block";
                $('#email').focus();
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("email_err").innerHTML= "";
                document.getElementById("email_err").style.display = "none";
            }
            if(pass==""){
                document.getElementById("password_err").innerHTML= "Password not be enmpty";
                document.getElementById("password_err").style.display = "block";
                $('#password').focus();
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("password_err").innerHTML= "";
                document.getElementById("password_err").style.display = "none";
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'userinfo.php',
                data: 'firstname=' + fname+ 'lastname=' + lname+ 'phone=' + phn+ 'emailid=' +emailid+ 'password=' + pass,
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            }); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I save in my admin using AJAX? I'm new for this language  when click on  submit button getting error not data are not stored in database.

I have created sign up form and user enter values the validation is perfectly working now I need to send  the data to database.

Comment: please post your html code too. I can provide you shorter code for this.

Comment: thank  you I am new In php I have   the predefined  code  and my task  to to send the data   to my sql  I am able  to perform  the validation  and not able  to send data to to data  base

Comment: Post your `html` code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Comment: show your `userinfo.php` code

Comment: let jquery format your data string like this: 
`data: {firstname: fname, lastname: lname, ....},` see if this fix your problem

Comment: Thank    you  I fix it .